# Impossibility of adding advice to final methods when using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm reading [this official page of Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) and then I read this sentence which I didn't understand :

> You cannot add advice to final methods when you use Spring MVC. For
>   example, you cannot add advice to the
>   AbstractController.setSynchronizeOnSession() method. Refer to Section
>   10.6.1, “Understanding AOP proxies” for more information on AOP proxies and why you cannot add advice to final methods.

Can anybody explain to me what they mean by this, and specially by **advice**?

Comment: `Advice` is a concept in `spring-aop`. Basically it is a method (or interceptor) that is invoked before, after or around invocation of others methods when certain conditions are met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An advice is a method that should be called before or after a method of another class is invoked.

An example could be a logging advice, that is attached to every method of a service to log out the invocation of every service method.

In order to attach an advice to a method, Spring subclasses the class, the method belongs to and overrides the method with an implementation that calls the advice when the method is invoked. Additionaly the proxy method will also call the overwritten method (the super method) to obtain the original functionality.

A final method cannot be overidden, so Spring cannot create a proxy and you cannat attach an advice.

Its a general limitation, that it is impossible to use a subclass proxy for final methods. It is not a special limitation for aspects.

Answer (score 1):

An *advice* isn't something specific to Spring MVC, but rather a concept from Aspect Oriented Programming (or AOP for short, see [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) for a general introduction).

The way Spring Beans work, and the way they allow for AOP, is by taken the class you annotated as a bean, and creating a proxy based on that class, which means on-the-fly / at runtime creating a subclass instance that inherits from your class and which provides custom implementations for each method ('overriding' them). As you know, overriding final methods is inherently impossible (that's what makes them *final*). That's the reason why the documentation states:

> you cannot add advice to final methods